# Struts2 s:checkbox label not showing up

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, weblogic

In the most bizarre of circumstances, the label for my checkbox do not show up in my Struts2 JSP. I have a series of checkboxes, all following the same format, but none of the labels appear. Here is a sample declaration:

```
<s:checkbox name="chronCheck1" label="New Sales"/>
```

This is among the most basic of tasks, but something is obviously missing. I am running Struts2 version 2.2.1 via Weblogic 10. Not really sure what else is necessary to help troubleshoot.

Comment: You can also try using key as a shorthand way.
 
key:Set the key (name, value, label) for this particular component

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/checkbox.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using `simple` theme in your JSP. With `simple` theme you must create labels for inputs by yourself.

About `simple` theme from documentation:

> For example, the textfield tag renders the HTML  tag without a label, validation, error reporting, or any other formatting or functionality.

See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from the official documentation for the s:checkbox, but in my experiment, if you don't specify the theme, the default theme does not support label. When I change the theme to either  *xhtml* or *css_xhtml* it successfully showed the label. However these themes also add additional markup and css classes, so you probably need extra css styling and specifying **labelposition** (top, left, right or bottom) to achieve your desired look and feel. Another option is to create your own theme and apply it. Please refer to this documentation:

https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-themes.html

Comment: `xhtml` is the default theme.